Neo4j Web Analytics model
I would like the depict the flow of paths followed by a user using Neo4j. I want to produce an output like a sankey diagram. The project I am doing requires a similar output like Google Analytics. Is using Neo4j a feasible option?
I have currently thought of storing the URL as nodes and the relationship between two nodes as relationship with type "PATH". The traversed path is stored as relationship property with a value.

For example if a user moves from A->B->C->D then the relationship
between A and B will have the property A_B:1 and the relationship
between B and C will have a relationship property AB_C:1.Relationship
between C and D will have a relationship property as ABC_D:1.

Does anyone have their own input to this? Is this a good model?

If you were to use Neo4j, it certainly makes sense to use nodes to model  states and relationships to model the flows between states.
But it is a very bad idea for you to try to maintain real-time flow information as extra properties in the data, since the real-time flow can be be gotten directly from the nodes and relationships without any extra data. Adding your own real-time flow properties would be totally redundant, add complexity, waste time and storage, and be vulnerable to race conditions (and therefore would not be reliable).

Could you please suggest a model.And how will i be able to get real-time flow directly from the nodes and relationships considering i need keep records of the number of users who have travelled from Url to the next url .for example if 10 users have landed in url A and from A, 7 have moved to url B and 3 have gone to url C .How do i keep track of this.I have to depict multiple hops similar to this.My data is also in millions of users.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Not quite clear on your use case. Are you trying to show the movement of a single user or the general movement pattern of multiple users? My answer is more geared towards the former. If it is the latter, then your original proposal may make sense. Also, these links show 2 possible ways to visualize a sankey diagram (using NeoDash or Excel): https://neo4j.com/labs/neodash/2.4/user-guide/reports/sankey/, https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/xls/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgyhBVAIDc0.

My goal is to store the user activity of multiple users for a group of sites in the graph database.So i have to model my data in such a way that i am able to efficiently query it to show number of users who have travelled from one site to another.Imagie 100 users move move from site A to B and another 2000 from site A to C.Another 100 from B to D.So the query should cover retrieve this information from the graph. For reference i will provide the query I have been working one.

MATCH (n:UrlNode {label: 'H'})-[r:PATH*]->(m:UrlNode)
WHERE ALL(rel IN r WHERE ANY(key IN keys(rel) WHERE key CONTAINS 'H'))
WITH n, m, r, [rel IN r | keys(rel)] AS allKeys
UNWIND allKeys AS keyList
UNWIND keyList AS key
WITH n, m, r, key
WHERE key CONTAINS 'H'
RETURN n, m, COLLECT(key) AS filteredkeys, r AS rels

I have edited the question to show the diagram that would be represented on the frontend of our  project.I am not concerned with the frontend.I only have to figure out a way to provide the backend storage layer to store the user data and query the number of users that have moved from one url to the next url.And the consecutive flow and count of the users
